# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen »Annahme« und »Vermutung«?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between *Vermutung* and *Annahme*?

In unterschiedlichen Kontexten habe ich *Annahme* und *Vermutung* gehört. Die englische Übersetzung für beide ist *assumption,* aber es gibt bestimmt einen Unterschied, oder? Welcher ist es? (Ist es derselbe wie zwischen [*presumption* und *assumption*](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/170560/42471)?

---

I’ve heard the words *Vermutung* and *Annahme* used in different contexts. Both translate to *assumption,* but what is the difference? (Is it the same as [*presumption* vs *assumption*](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/170560/42471)?)

(Note: before someone edits it out, I want to point out that the reason I repeated the question at the top is so that someone can read the extract and know the question without opening it. It's also so that the question is bilingual but if I were to write the question twice it would be long and cut off, leaving the English part invisible and defeating the purpose.)

Comment: Vom Sinn her kein Unterschied.

Comment: @rogermue: Mal angenommen, das würde stimmen, dann hätte ich diesen Satz auch mit "Mal vermutet" beginnen können.

Comment: Vermutung heißt auf Englisch "conjecture".

Comment: @MartinPeters: Ich mag mich ja irren, aber ich habe das Wort noch niemal außerhalb der Mathematik gehört. Es fällt mir schwer vorzustellen, dass jemand z. B. sagen würde: »My conjecture is that it will rain tomorrow.«

Comment: Es gibt eine Paketannahme, aber keine Paketvermutung. Falls doch wäre letzteres kein Schalter in der Post.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft In der Mathematik ist das Wort natürlich nicht weg zu denken, aber "conjecture" kommt auch in ganz normaler Belletristik vor, zum Beispiel bei dem Schriftsteller Thomas Hardy.

Comment: user unknown, Das ist dann aber eine ganz andere Bedeutung, die natürlich grundsätzlich etwas anderes meint und daher nicht das gleiche wie Vermutung bedeutet.

@chirlu
ja, hätte man natürlich. Wenn man über den Satz "Mal vermutet, das würde stimmen..." nachdenkt, dürfte man zu dem Ergebnis kommen, dass er genau das gleiche bedeutet wie "Mal angenommen, das ...". Es hat sich jedoch nur die "Mal angenommen"-Formulierung eingebürgert. Nur weil ein mit "Mal vermutet" anfangender Satz absolut ungebräuchlich ist, heißt das ja noch lange nicht, dass er syntaktisch oder semantisch falsch ist.

Comment: @anion: Wie die Antworten darstellen, setzt _vermuten_ voraus, daß man das Gesagte für wahrscheinlich hält.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- Eine ***Vermutung*** ist eine Aussage, von der man nicht weiß, ob sie wahr ist, und deren Zutreffen man zumindest für wahrscheinlicher hält als ihr Nicht-Zutreffen.
- Eine ***Annahme*** ist eine Vermutung, Hypothese oder ein Fall, der als Voraussetzung für weitere Aussagen oder Argumente dient. Letztere können auch implizit sein.

Dies lässt sich auch analog auf *annehmen* und *vermuten* übertragen.

Da man Vermutungen eigentlich nie um ihrer selbst willen tätigt, kann *Vermutung* fast immer durch *Annahme* ersetzt werden. Eine Ausnahme stellt die Mathematik dar, in der *Vermutung* als Fachbegriff für unbewiesene und unwiderlegte Aussagen (die in der Regel empirisch gut untermauert sind) genutzt wird, z. B. die Riemannsche Vermutung. (Dank an [Matthias](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/9091/matthias).)

Umgekehrt sind aber nicht alle Annahmen Vermutungen, sondern nur die meisten. Zum Beispiel:

- > Unter der Annahme, dass ich den Zug erwische, bin ich in einer Stunde zuhause.

  Ich mache hier keine Aussage darüber, wie wahrscheinlich es ist, dass ich den Zug erwische. Ich könnte *unter der Annahme, dass* genauso gut durch *wenn* ersetzen.
- > Angenommen, Du spielst den Bauern; dann verliert Deine Dame ihre Deckung und mein König schlägt sie. Angenommen, Du spielst die Dame; dann setze ich Dich sofort schachmatt. Wie Du auch ziehst, ich gewinne.

  Hier ist es ziemlich klar, dass der Sprecher keine Aussage darüber trifft, welchen Zug er für wahrscheinlicher hält. Jede Annahme ist ein Fall, dessen Konsequenzen kurz diskutiert werden (um zu dem Schluss zu gelangen, dass es keine Rolle spielt, welcher Fall zutrifft).
- > Ideale Gase sind ein Modell, das unter anderem auf der Annahme basiert, dass die Gasteilchen punktförmig sind.

  Dieses Beispiel geht noch einen Schritt weiter: Der Sprecher weiß in aller Regel, dass die Annahme nicht zutrifft (Gasteilchen haben eine Ausdehnung) und dennoch macht er sie, da sie das Modell vereinfacht und oft eine hinreichend gute Näherung darstellt. (Dank an [Idmean](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/4701/idmean) für das Beispiel.)
- > Um die Vermutung, dass π irrational ist, zu beweisen, nehmen wir an, dass es rational ist, und führen dies zum Widerspruch.

  Hier vermutet oder weiß der Sprecher, dass seine Annahme falsch ist. (Dank an [Daniel](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/17106/daniel) für das Beispiel.)

In keinem dieser Fälle kann *Annahme* durch *Vermutung* ersetzt werden (oder analog).

Comment: Also der gleiche Unterschied zwischen die englischen Wörtern _presumption_ und _assumption_.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Schöne Umschreibung der Bedeutung von _Vermutung_ in der Mathematik!

Comment: `Eine Annahme ist eine Vermutung` ... arr ... ein Hund kam in die Küche ...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: Solange ich nicht *Annahme* nutze um *Vermutung* zu definieren, ist doch alles in Ordnung.

Comment: absolut, das meinte ich auch nicht - war wohl etwas missverständlich - aber egal (das *arr* war nicht negativ gemeint)

Answer (score 3):

Man kann die Wörter allgemein synonym zueinander verwenden.

Benutzen tut man die Wörter im Fachbereich manchmal lediglich kontextabhängig:

Wenn man eine Annahme hat, ist das in der Wissenschaft meistens eher eine hypothetische Grundlage für weitere Schlussfolgerungen. ("Unter der Annahme, dass Aussage A gilt, schließe ich, dass auch Aussage B gilt.")

Wenn beispielsweise in der Wissenschaft von einer Vermutung die Rede ist, ist damit oft eine Art Hypothese gemeint, die es zu belegen oder widerlegen gilt.

Vermutung ist ein "stärkerer" Begriff als Annahme, das heißt, bei einer Vermutung ist man sich sicherer, dass sie (aufgrund bestimmter nennbarer Gründe) gilt, als bei einer einfachen Annahme.

Das ist jetzt aber reines Sprach- und Semantik-Gefühl basierend auf meinen Erfahrungen, es gibt sicherlich auch viele Menschen, die das anders sehen.

So richtig strikt abgrenzbar sind diese Begriffe auch von dem Begriff der These anscheinend leider nicht, aber ich lasse mich auch gern eines Besseren belehren.

Comment: Ich glaube, man verwendet Wörter synonym und nicht synonym zueinander. Da du uns in deiner Antwort erklärst, dass die beiden Wörter unterschiedliche Bedeutung haben ist es nicht richtig, dass du sie als synonym bezeichnest..

Comment: vorweg habe ich geschrieben "Man kann die Wörter _allgemein_ synonym zueinander verwenden" um zu verdeutlichen, dass eine unterscheidung von "annahme" und "vermutung" _meistens_ nicht nötig ist.
in manchen _speziellen_ kontexten werden die wörter jedoch mit leicht unterschiedlicher bedeutung benutzt, eben das wollte ich erklären.

Comment: solche spezialfälle, in denen es unpassend ist, "annahme" und "vermutung" geneinander auszutauschen, müssen oft extra konstruiert werden und kommen sehr selten im natürlichen sprachgebrauch vor  (siehe chirlus ersten kommentar auf diese frage für so ein konstruiertes beispiel). ob die wörter synonym sind, hängt also mehr von der präzisionsebene ab, auf der man sich artikulieren möchte.